# iOS websocket without handshake

Tags: ios, sockets, websocket, handshake

I want to establish a simple local Socket communication on iOS. After looking into other libraries, I found the websocket lib that is now native to Swift since last year works quite well, but comes with a nasty handshake that I would like to disable (otherwise I would have to adjust the server response etc.). My code looks like this:

```
let webSocketDelegate = WebSocket()
                let session = URLSession(configuration: .default, delegate: webSocketDelegate, delegateQueue: OperationQueue())
                let url = URL(string: "ws://192.168.43.1:6000")!
                let webSocketTask = session.webSocketTask(with: url)
                func send() {
                    DispatchQueue.global().asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
                        send()
                        webSocketTask.send(.string("New Message")) { error in
                          if let error = error {
                            print("Error when sending a message \(error)")
                          }
                        }
                    }
                }

             
                webSocketTask.receive { result in
                  switch result {
                  case .success(let message):
                    switch message {
                    case .data(let data):
                      print("Data received \(data)")
                    case .string(let text):
                      print("Text received \(text)")
                    }
                  case .failure(let error):
                    print("Error when receiving \(error)")
                  }
                  
                }
                
                webSocketTask.resume()
```

I googled and found [nw_ws_options_set_skip_handshake](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/network/3172639-nw_ws_options_set_skip_handshake?language=objc#discussion), but I could not find an example how to use it. Any ideas?

Comment: Without the initial handshake it is actually not Websocket protocol. Why not use plain TCP sockets then?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich As I said, I checked various libs, but maybe just websocket ones. I looked into TCP and made it work. Thanks for the pointer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @SteffenUllrich suggested, I looked more into TCP socket communication and found a simple way to communicate. Here my solution, hope it will help someone else:

```
 let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "TCP Client Queue")
        let connection = NWConnection(to: NWEndpoint.hostPort(host: "192.168.99.1", port: 7000), using: NWParameters.init(tls: nil))
           
        func connect() {
            
            connection.stateUpdateHandler = { (newState) in
                switch (newState) {
                case .ready:
                    print("Socket: ready")
                    sendString(text: "Hello server!")
                    receiveMsg()
                default: print("Socket: \(newState)")
                }
            }
            connection.start(queue: queue)
            }
            
        func receiveMsg() {
            connection.receive(minimumIncompleteLength: 1, maximumLength: 1000, completion: { (data, context, isComplete, error) in
                if((data) != nil){
                    let text:String = String(decoding: data!, as: UTF8.self)
                    //send string to handler function, trim linebreak for single line commands
                    handleMsg(msg: text.trimmingCharacters(in: .newlines))
                }
                else{receiveMsg()//go back to receiving}
            })
        }
        
        func receiveFile() {
            print("Receiving file...")
//fileSize was sent before submission 
            connection.receive(minimumIncompleteLength: Int(fileSize), maximumLength: Int(fileSize)+1000, completion: { (data, context, isComplete, error) in
                saveFile(data: data!)//save data to file
            })
        }
        
        func sendString(text:String) {
                let data:Data? = "\(text)\n".data(using: .utf8)//add linebreak to single line string, otherwise it does not release transmission
                connection.send(content: data, completion: NWConnection.SendCompletion.contentProcessed(({ (NWError) in
                    if (NWError == nil) {
                        print("Data was sent to TCP destination ")
                    } else {
                        print("ERROR! Error when data (Type: Data) sending. NWError: \n \(NWError!)")
                    }
                })))
            }
```

You just need to call connect() to start the connection, use sendString() to send some text. Receiving should run constantly. I didn't share the command handler, but it re-runs receiveMsg() on a regular command, and receiveFile() when a file transmission is initiated by the server (the init also contains the fileSize required to set the expected bytesize in the receive() function!).